# wildcard searching for filename in folder with preg_match?

Tags: php, search, wildcard

i've code with which i want to check if there is some file located in folder. Every file has at start of filename 00'.$id'-time() so some example "00226-1413203222.pdf".

i have this code for checking if there is some file with that id :

```
$id = 226;
$searchpath = "files/00" . $id . "-*";

if (file_exists($searchpath)) {
...
...
...
```

but this code don't want to work, so probably i need some other method to do this?

Can u give me some good advices how to do this best way?

Thank you

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: i tried this but no success for now :/

Comment: Show us _what_ you have tried.

Comment: Works now, i figured it out with: $searchpath = glob("files/00".$id."-*");

if (empty($searchpath)) {
$fileexist = "no";
}
else {
    $fileexist = "yes";
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use [scandir()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.scandir.php) like so

```
$id = "26";
$dir_path = "files";
$fileSearchRegex = "/^00".$id."-[0-9]*\.pdf$/";

$foundFile = array_map(function($file){
    if(preg_match($fileSearch, $file))
        return $file;
}, scandir($dir_path));
```